# Initialize List using getter setter

Tags: java, android

I am trying to initialize a List using setter method in same class when I will receive a response but when I called getter from other class its returning an empty list. Is it technically possible what I'm trying to achieve?

```
public class CategoryCommonAPI
{
    private Context context;
    private String endUrl;
    private UserAccessToken userAccessToken;
    private String ITV_BASE_URL;
    private  List<CategoryCommonResponse> itemq;


    public CategoryCommonAPI(Context context, String endUrl, List<CategoryCommonResponse> itemq)
    {
         this.context = context;
         this.endUrl = endUrl;
         this.itemq = itemq;
         ITV_BASE_URL = context.getString(R.string.baseUrl);
         userAccessToken = new UserAccessToken(context);
    }

    public void getAllCategory()
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Iam thanos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        String token ="Bearer "+userAccessToken.getAccessToken();
        final ITV_API_Service itvApiService = RetrofitClient.getClient(ITV_BASE_URL).create(ITV_API_Service.class);
        itvApiService.categoriesItem(endUrl,token).enqueue(new Callback<List<CategoryCommonResponse>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<CategoryCommonResponse>> call, Response<List<CategoryCommonResponse>> response)
        {
            if (response.isSuccessful())
            {
                List<CategoryCommonResponse> item = response.body();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Iam called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                setItem(item);




            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<CategoryCommonResponse>> call, Throwable t)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Image response failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });
}

private void setItem(List<CategoryCommonResponse> item)
{
    this.itemq= item;

    Log.d("List size", "setItem: "+item.size());
    Log.d("Return List", "setItem: "+itemq.size());
}

public List<CategoryCommonResponse> getItemq()
{
    return this.itemq;
}
}
```

and where I'm calling it is

```
CategoryCommonAPI commonAPI = new CategoryCommonAPI(this, endUrl, list);
      commonAPI.getAllCategory();
      list=commonAPI.getItemq();
```

When I checked the list.size() using toast or Log.d it show 0 item.

Comment: The service appears to be asynchronous - meaning when `getAllCatagory` returns the response has not yet been processed and therefore the list is not populated.

Comment: Yet response is successful but I'm getting an empty List,So what is the best practice for achieve this?

Comment: You'll need to implement a callback such that when `onResponse` is invoked the callback (to the caller) is executed - or manage the synchronization between the service and the caller in some way.  But first - it's best to fully understand the asynchronous aspect of your posted code - and then the solution will become clearer.

Comment: @Saddan yes the response was successful but by the time it was recieved the program had already executed the next line where you are retrieving it.

Answer (score 0):

Since its an asynchronous call and you are trying to retrieve the list immediately after it then one possible way is to return the list after setting from the getAllCategory() method itself.

Comment: I just tried to return the List using `getAllCatagory` method but still it's returning an empty list,but inside response body its showing 26,I'm mesmerized whats really happening to my code